# Loading dynamic data into a dynamic element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I make an ajax call that returns json data and tells me what html template to load and also the data needed to populate the template. If I load the template outside of the ajax call the data populates fine, however if i try and load the html within the ajax call, i see the html elements have loaded, but i am unable to populate them.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://some-url/items-json/item_data.json",
dataType: "json",
async: true,
success: function( data ) {

     // template_name will be an html file like template_10.html
     // #player-template is the div id i want to load it into   
     $('#player-template').load(data.template_name);


    // these elements get created from the dynamic template that gets loaded above
    $('#ques_intro').html(data.ques_intro);
    $('#question').html(data.question);
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use the complete call back argument of load, so that the elements added during load `#ques_intro` etc is accessible once the load is complete. Other wise it will run load and other statements as load being async.

```
 $('#player-template').load(data.template_name, function(){ // <-- Call back executes after the load is complete.
    $('#ques_intro').html(data.ques_intro); //Now you can access the elements as they will be available in DOM
    $('#question').html(data.question);

   });
```

**[.load( url , complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) )](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to specify a callback handler so that you wait until your template has been loaded to insert the content.

As per the [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) spec, you simply need to pass in a callback handler after the load argument.

For example..

```
$('#player-template').load(data.template_name,function(){
    $('#ques_intro').html(data.ques_intro);
    $('#question').html(data.question);
});
```